# Custom TypeScript type guard for "not undefined" in separate function

Tags: typescript

This won't compile:

```
public hello(user?: User): void {
  // ...do some stuff
  console.log(user.toString());      // error: "Object is possibly undefined" 
}
```

That can be fixed with a type guard:

```
if (!user) throw Error();
```

But I want to move that into a separate function, so I tried

```
private guard(arg: unknown): arg is object {
  if (!arg) throw Error();
}
```

and I tried

```
private guard(arg: unknown): arg is object {
 return arg !== undefined;
}
```

But that doesn't work.

How do I write a custom type guard in a separate function, to assert "not undefined"?

Comment: Maybe something like this? `function check<T>(x: T | undefined) { return x || error("Undefined value"); }`

Comment: @PatrickHollweck Thanks. That doesn't work for me. I also tried that with throwing though that also doesn't work.

Comment: @Titian I didn't finish reading your answer before you deleted it... You used animals, my favorite type of example! And there were chickens involved too! :)

Comment: Posted on the wrong question, there is another one with chicken :P. Was just looking at yours and this code seems to work fine: https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3lAhgLinYRASwDsBzKAXwCgAzAVxIGNgiB7EqACwgBte2ACnoJEAfjzwkASjwA3NkQAmGalChFaUQWXpZES4aOnTV69Uw5w2vCADoBZI0jvA2AZUKknJgNxqqaho6RhZ2Tl19Q30yPEYAaxI2AHcSWWxECiI4KDYAIwArCBYzKEQIYHpEThioAEIUNEYlCFpSCCV-SiA

Comment: If you are looking for a no `if` solution then that is not currently possible ..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Lol thanks as always Titian! For the record, chicken examples are my favorite. That link works for me, thanks. Pity the `if` can't be eliminated but it's good enough! Maybe copy-pasta into an answer so I can close?

Comment: Also I didn't know about [typescript-play.js.org](https://typescript-play.js.org) what an awesome resource!

Comment: posted, You can finish reading the animal example here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54736082/changing-a-variables-type-in-typescript/54736171#54736171 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have should work, this contained example works as is:

```
type User = { a: string }
function hello(user?: User): void {
  if (guard(user)) {
    console.log(user.toString());
  }
}

function guard(arg: unknown): arg is object {
  return arg !== undefined;
}
```

If you are looking for a version that does not require an `if` that is not currently possible, all type guards require some form of conditional statement (`if` or `switch`)

Answer (score 31):

You could use a template function like this:

```js
function isDefined<T>(val: T | undefined | null): val is T {
    return val !== undefined && val !== null;
}
```

This one checks for not `undefined` and not `null`.

Comment: Thanks for this, I needed a function that checked for undefined, null, OR empty string but with the one I had Typescript kept thinking items it would return `true` on could be undefined. I was able to adapt this to work `export function hasValue<T> (input: T | undefined | null): input is T {
  if (input === undefined || input === null) {
    return false
  } else if (typeof input === 'string' && input === '') {
    return false
  } else {
    return true
  }
}`

Comment: @dwllama those are all falsy values for a string. So a simple IF statement should have the same result.

Comment: Maybe it is my linter/formatter that complains (using `ts-standard`) but if I just check 'if' on a value that isn't a boolean, I get errors.  Plus, `hasValue` can work to check other things vs null or undefined besides just strings. I use it everywhere.

Comment: better use the ramda or lodash-es !isNil function, or, if you accept the usage of "==" and "!=", val != null

Answer (score 1):

As of TypeScript 3.7 which was released in Nov 2019, there are [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions).

```
function assertIsDefined<T>(val: T): asserts val is NonNullable<T> {
  if (val === undefined || val === null) {
    throw new AssertionError(
      `Expected 'val' to be defined, but received ${val}`
    );
  }
}

function hello(user?: User): void {
  assertIsDefined(user);
  console.log(user.toString()); // Here user is User
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the lodash helpers which [already have type guards defined on them](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/4486794741ccb9f18f562fefade043ac31e817de/types/lodash/common/lang.d.ts#L1055).

```js
import * as _ from 'lodash'
type User = {a: string}
function hello(user?: User): void {
  if (_.isObject(user)) {
    console.log(user.toString())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `Exclude` for this :

```
export function isDefined<T>(
    unkownTypeVariable: T
): unkownTypeVariable is Exclude<T, undefined> {
    return unkownTypeVariable !== undefined
}
```

Note: I personaly don't tend to use `NonNullable` because I like not mixing `null` and `undefined`. I think separating both is a powerfull feature in some cases (eg. when patching you could distinguish between erasing a member and just omiting it).