# Changing a variable's type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

So here's my problem, let's say I have some types of animals:

```
interface IAnimal {
   type: string;
   legs: number;
}

interface IChicken extends IAnimal {
   eggsPerDay: number;
}

interface ICow extends IAnimal {
   milkProduction: number;
}

...

doSomethingWithAnimal(animal: IChicken|ICow): void {
    switch(animal.type){
        case 'cow':
            alert(`the milk production is ${animal.milkProduction}`);
    }
}
```

The problem that I have is typescript doesn't know if it's a cow or a chicken. Is there a way that once I know for sure that the animal is of type ICow that I can safely access those additional attributes?

I know that it's possible to do `const cow = animal as ICow` but wouldn't that needlessly copy my variable? The example that I provided is an oversimplification since the problem that I'm actually trying to solve has ten derived classes and the function is called a ton, so I want to keep it as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a discriminated union for this task. You just need to add a `type` member to each memebr of the union with the actual type as a string literal type:

```
interface IAnimal {
  type: string;
  legs: number;
}

interface IChicken extends IAnimal {
  type: "chicken";
  eggsPerDay: number;
}

interface ICow extends IAnimal {
  type: "cow";
  milkProduction: number;
}

function doSomethingWithAnimal(animal: IChicken | ICow): void {
  switch (animal.type) {
    case 'cow':
      alert(`the milk production is ${animal.milkProduction}`); // ok now
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below,

```
  doSomethingWithAnimal(animal: IChicken | ICow): void {
    if(animal.hasOwnProperty('eggsPerDay')) {
      console.log('eggsPerDay', animal.eggsPerDay)
    } else if (animal.hasOwnProperty('milkProduction')) {
      console.log('milkProduction', animal.milkProduction)
    }; // other conditions
  }
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-411g4b) code for reference

Comment: I would recommend using an `in` instead, that also acts as a TS type guard:https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEETALZwDbIDeAUMmWAJ4AOEAXMgM5hSgDmA3KWXhKw-SACu2AEbROAX2LFQkWIhSoAwgAtgCANYQQyCAA9IIACYM0mHPiJddrPgAVoAETgUBwsVEnTZ0eEjRKAPYA7roG2iZmWLgEJGTI2MB4GnZQgUaCCGDAgSBuouLEUsQwgiBZOTpGgQDKgdgQYGogrADqwE3mMQAUcNH49MpqmtoAPsohAJT0AG6BwEZW8cjAMN0A5InJqemZ2bnrKzp9FniTS8vICLkMgTwAdHiBrL39ePdbKWkZFbmT1sgJBA8AwIHFLtcQLcHk8XicYvdePYnC5-gCpBIgA

Comment: I think that @TitianCernicova-Dragomir has an answer closer to what I was going for since animal.eggsPerDay would still cause en error.

Comment: @SethKillian, No problem. But what do you mean by **animal.eggsPerDay would still cause en error.**

Comment: A Typescript error. `hasOwnProperty` does not narrow the type of the parameter. That is why I recommend an `in` expression